# Дана структура. Почему для 2-ого объекта поля "name" не активно, а сразу переходит к "lastname"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct subject
{
    int math;
    int phisics;
    int history;
};

struct student
{
    char *name;
    char *latname;
    int group;
    subject sub;
};

void input(student *st)
{
    char name[50];
    cout << "Введите имя: ";
    gets_s(name);   
    st->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(st->name, name); 

    cout << "Введите фамилию: ";
    gets_s(name);   
    st->latname = new char[strlen(name) + 1];   
    strcpy(st->latname, name);

    cout << "Введите № группы: ";
    cin >> st->group;

    cout << "Оцента по математике: ";
    cin >> st->sub.math;

    cout << "Оцента по истории: ";
    cin >> st->sub.history;

    cout << "Оцента по физике: ";
    cin >> st->sub.phisics; 
}

void show(student *st)
{
    cout << "Имя: " << st->name << endl;
    cout << "Фамилия: " << st->latname << endl;
    cout << "Группа: " << st->group << endl;
    cout << "Оцента по математике: " << st->sub.math << endl;
    cout << "Оцента по истории: " << st->sub.history << endl;
    cout << "Оцента по физике: " << st->sub.phisics << endl;
}

void clean(student *st)
{
    delete st->name;
    delete st->latname;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(NULL, "RUS");
    student a;
    input(&a);      

    student b;
    input(&b);

    show(&a);
    show(&b);

    clean(&a);
    clean(&b);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что после ввода числа в буфере остается символ `'\n'`. Он и считывается при вводе строки как пустая строка. Вам надо сбросить содержимое буфера перед вводом строки:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

При неверном вводе числа нужно еще сбросить флаг состояния ошибки `cin.clear()`.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо. А можно как нибудь по другому решить эту проблему, мне не понятно то что Вы написали

Comment: Читайте по одному символу все, пока не встретите '\n', и только потом начинайте читать строку.